# Pack individual signal into an array

Tags: system-verilog

I have a bunch of signals like this:

```
logic [7:0] in0;
logic [7:0] in1;
logic [7:0] in2;
logic [7:0] in3;
```

That I want to assign to an array:

```
logic [7:0] in_array [4];
assign in_array[0] = in0;
assign in_array[1] = in1;
assign in_array[2] = in2;
assign in_array[3] = in3;
```

Easy enough, but if instead of 4 items I have 128 this gets annoying. I am sure there is a combination of defines and generates that can do this in a loop.  Something like:

```
`define IN(x) inx
genvar i;
generate
   for(i = 0; i<4; i++) begin
      assign in_array[i] = `IN(i);
   end 
endgenerate
```

The above code doesn't work, but I think that I have done something like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying that code is something that cannot be done in SystemVerilog. You can reduce you typing by creating a macro like below (note the double backticks ``` `` ```), but you will still need to manually write each index. Macros are are resolved before generate loops and the input variable to the macro is treated as a literal.

```
// short named macro for reduced typing
//   Note: using short named macro is typically a bad practice,
//         but will be removed latter with an undef
`define A(idx) assign array_in[idx] = out``idx
//This works
`A(0);
`A(1);
`A(2);
`A(3);

// doesn't work. For example @ gidx==0 will eval to 'assign array_in[0] = outgidx;'.
// There is not outgidx
genvar gidx;
generate
  for(gidx=0; gidx<4; gidx++) begin
    `A(gidx); 
  end
endgenerate

`undef A // prevent macro from from being used latter on
```

If it is just a small number of entries, it is best to do it manually. If it is large number of entries, then you need to consider a way to generate the for you, such as embedded coded.

There are also various embedded code (such as Perl's [EP3](http://search.cpan.org/~gspivey/Text-EP3-Verilog-1.00/Verilog.pm), Ruby's [eRuby](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/eruby.htm)/[ruby_it](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby_it), Python's [prepro](http://corner-case.com/indproj/prepro.html), etc.) that can generate the desired code. Pick your preference. You will need to per-process these files before giving to the compiler. Example with [EP3](http://search.cpan.org/~gspivey/Text-EP3-Verilog-1.00/Verilog.pm) generating 400 assignments:

```
@perl_begin
  foreach my $idx (0..400) {
    printf "assign array_in[%0d] = out%0d;", $idx, $idx;
  }
@perl_end
```

Comment: Well, not ideal, but your macro idea does prevent my biggest fear: a typo that swaps two values. I will look into EP3 and also try to figure out if emacs verilog mode can do this since I already use that extensively.

Answer (score 0):

Use `` to separate text from argument.

```
`define IN(x) in``x
```

But there is another issue with the variable `i` not being declared at the time when the macro is evaluated. Thus the whole generate loop just connects to `ini`, because `i` is just another letter. Because of this macros cannot be assigned by dynamically allocated values.

The environment of your module already has to connect explicitly to each input `assign in0 = out0; ... assign in127 = out127`. So the simplest solution would be to have `in_array` as your modules input and let the environment connect to it `assign array_in[0] = out0`.

Something like this:

```
module parent_module();

/*some other stuff that has outputs out0, out1 etc.*/

logic [7:0] array_in[4]; 

assign array_in[0] = out0;    
assign array_in[1] = out1;
assign array_in[2] = out2;
assign array_in[3] = out3;

my_module(.array_in(array_in));
endmodule
```